# How to automatically update files in github

Tags: git, github, upload, repository, auto-update

I have a local copy of a github repo on my machine but I would like it to either

- Update the repo with the local version automatically
- Update when I execute a command in the terminal

I am using [this repo](https://github.com/kk6axq/ros_arduino_bridge).

Currently I am just copying and pasting from one file to another but I realize I will mess up at some point. Is there a way to accomplish this easily?

Thanks

Comment: Would you always use the local repository as the source for the changes you want to commit to your github repository?

Comment: What's wrong with `git commit` and `git push` ?